# Fit Text in UItableView Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have a long label that is my first label, and I want to fit it in my cell. This is what I have but it isn't working.

I have a custom UITabelviewCell with a few labels in it.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:{

        CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

        CGSize size = [diningHallTimes[indexPath.row][@"description"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

            return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2) + 40;
//            return myStringSize.height;
            break;
        }
        default:
            return 40;
            break;
    }   
}
```

Here is cell for row

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

DiningInfoTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

CGSize size = [diningHallTimes[indexPath.row][@"description"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

CGFloat the =  height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);
cell.descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

[cell.descriptionLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 280, the)];

NSLog(@"%f", the);


cell.descriptionLabel.text = diningHallTimes[indexPath.row][@"description"];
cell.daysLabel.text = diningHallTimes[indexPath.row][@"days"];
cell.timeLabel.text = diningHallTimes[indexPath.row][@"time"];

return cell;
}
```

But then this is what my cell looks like

[image]

Not sure why this is happening, I am running iOS8, but I need it to work for both is and 7.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate `boundingRectWithSize:` for label text. Also need to calculate number of lines required for updated content also. Try this below method to calculate new frame for label.

```
- (UILabel *) updateLabelFrame:(UILabel *)label {

    CGRect lblRect = label.frame;
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT);

    CGRect labelRect = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:maxSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:label.font} context:nil];

    CGFloat labelHeight = labelRect.size.height;

    // For below line 16 is default height (The height before content is set). Change this value
    // as per your requirement

    int lines = labelHeight / 16; // Here 16 is a fix height (default height) for label.
    [label setNumberOfLines:lines];
    lblRect.size.height = labelHeight;
    [label setFrame:lblRect];

    return label;
}
```

**Edit:**

You can place this method any where you want. Like some base class or in same view controller. Here I modified above method which will return label with dynamic frame.

For your case you need to place this method in view controller class. Then call this method in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath` after content is updated for label. See below code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    DiningInfoTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH - (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2), 20000.0f);

    CGSize size = [diningHallTimes[indexPath.row][@"description"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

    CGFloat the =  height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2);
    cell.descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    [cell.descriptionLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 280, the)];

    NSLog(@"%f", the);


    cell.descriptionLabel.text = diningHallTimes[indexPath.row][@"description"];
    cell.daysLabel.text = diningHallTimes[indexPath.row][@"days"];
    cell.timeLabel.text = diningHallTimes[indexPath.row][@"time"];

    // Update descriptionLabel height.

    cell.descriptionLabel = [self updateLabelFrame:cell.descriptionLabel];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: okay but I am using a label in a custom cell, so self.label gives error I need to be able to use the label from the cell

Comment: @iqueqiorio - Add this method in your view controller and pass label as argument in above method. Check answer I have updated method with arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set up Autolayout constraints for the label and create a prototype cell with the content. And then you have to return then you have to get the height of the cell.

For reference , you could see the following video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KImie4ZMwk

Comment: I am not using auto layout, could it be done without it?

Comment: It can be done with a lot of work without AL. Personally I would use AL. It will save you a ton of time writing code that is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try `[yourLabel sizeToFit]` or you may use `[yourLabel sizeThatFit:CGFrame];`